# Help with calculating the integral of $\sum _{n=1 } ^{\infty } [g _n (x)-g _{n+1 } (x) ]g _n (y)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I need help with computing the following integral. The point is that this is a case when fubini's theorem does not apply, and the interated integrals aren't equal.

Let $\mu $ and $\lambda $ be lebesgue measure on $[0,1 ]$ and let $0<\delta _n < \delta _2 ...<1 $ be a sequence such that $\delta _n \to 1 $.

Define $g _n $ such that it is continous with support in $(\delta _n , \delta _{n+1 } )$ and such that $\int_0 ^1 g _n (t) dt=1 $ for each $n $.

Define $f(x,y)=\sum _{n=1 } ^{\infty } [g _n (x)-g _{n+1 } (x) ]g _n (y)$

---

I want to calculate $\int ( \int f _x (y) d \lambda (y) ) d \mu (x) $ and the reverse order.

I try as follows, if I fix $n $ in the sum, then

$\int ( \int f _x (y) d \lambda (y) ) d \mu (x) = \int ((g _1(x)- g _2 (x))\int g _1(y) + (g _{n } -g _{n+1 } ) \int g _n)=\int ((g _1 (x)-g _2(x))+...(g _n(x)-g _{n+1 } )=0$

This is true for every $n $. What happens when I take the limit?

But if this calculation was done correctyly I believe the reverse order of integration again evaluates to $0 $ for each $n $. This shouldn't be so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when I take the limit?

The point is that you don't need to take a limit. In the iterated integrals, for each fixed $x\in [0,1]$, there are at most two $n$ such that $[g_n(x) - g_{n+1}(x)]g_n(y)$ *may* be nonzero, and for the other order of integration, for each fixed $y\in [0,1]$, there is only one $n$ such that $[g_n(x) - g_{n+1}(x)]g_n(y)$ may be nonzero.

So in fact you're dealing with finite sums in the iterated integrals.